# When is it safe to use .toString()?

Tags: javascript, tostring

Doesn't value have to return toString() to be able to call value.toString()? When do you know you can call value.toString()?

```
<script>
var newList = function(val, lst)
{
  return {
    value: val,
    tail:  lst,
    toString: function() 
    {
      var result = this.value.toString();
      if (this.tail != null)
        result += "; " + this.tail.toString();
      return result;
    },
    append: function(val)
    {
      if (this.tail == null)
        this.tail = newList(val, null);
      else
        this.tail.append(val);
    }
  };
}

var list = newList("abc", null); // a string
list.append(3.14); // a floating-point number
list.append([1, 2, 3]); // an array
document.write(list.toString());
</script>
```

Comment: Real questions have a verb and a question mark

Comment: I said "Doesn't value have to return toString() to be able to call value.toString()? When do you know you can call value.toString()?".

Comment: This question really doesn't have anything to do with linked lists.

Comment: Maybe you could give a more meaningful heading than "linked list" so that it could be of use to others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Every object in JavaScript has a toString() method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ToString)

Comment: No, not all objects. null has no properties. Also undefined has no properties, though it is not an object. https://jsfiddle.net/bca30e5h/

Comment: @Aurimas `null` is not really an object. The JS spec is confused about this. Null pointers _lack_ an object. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808300/7867) and other answers to that question.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for correcting me. In any case, it's still worth pointing out that there are cases when toString is not safe to use.

Comment: simple solution is

`if (val) result = val.toString()`

Answer (score 5):

As [Mr. Shiny and New](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050916/linked-list/1050999#1050999) states, *all* JavaScript objects have a `toString` method.  However, that method is not always useful, especially for custom classes and object literals, which tend to return strings like `"[Object object]"`.

You can create your own `toString` methods by adding a function with that name to your class' prototype, like so:

```
function List(val, list) {
    this.val = val;
    this.list = list;

    // ...
}

List.prototype = {
    toString: function() {
        return "newList(" + this.val + ", " + this.list + ")";
    }
};
```

Now, if you create a `new List(...)` and call its `toString` method (or run it through any function or operator that converts it to a string implicitly), your custom `toString` method will be used.

Finally, to detect whether an object has a `toString` method defined for its class (note that this will **not** work with subclassing or object literals; that is left as an exercise for the reader), you can access its `constructor`'s `prototype` property:

```
if (value.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("toString")) {
    alert("Value has a custom toString!");
}
```

Comment: Heh.  I do that all the time in Real Life, too.  I guess that's what I get for working in too many different languages.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

document.write, like window.alert, calls its argument's toString method before it writes or returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct that `toString` exists on all Javascript objects.

In general, though, if you want to know if a function exists on your object, you can test it like so:

```
if (obj.myMethod) {
    obj.myMethod();
}
```

This does not, of course, ensure that `myMethod` is a function instead of a property. But presumably you'll know that.