# How can I find out why two objects do not compare equal with angular.equals?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following **AngularJS code**:

```
if (angular.equals(rowData, $scope.grid.backup[i])) {
   console.log('equal')
}
```

Please note that AngularJS has an equals function that compares each element inside the object.

The two objects look equal when I debug but Angular does not agree. I just cannot see what is not equal. Is there some other way I can do a comparison?

Comment: Wait a second. Are you aware of what AngularJS equals does? It compares each of the elements one by one to see if they match. Your answer does not make sense for this question.

Comment: @SamanthaJ Ya, my bad.  Deleting comments and retracting vote.  Again, sorry.

Comment: @Alan Is an example possible of the objects you're comparing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The doc for `angular.equals()` says:

> Two objects or values are considered equivalent if at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> Both objects or values pass === comparison.
>
> Both objects or values are of the same type and all of their properties are equal by comparing them with angular.equals.
>
> Both values are NaN. (In JavaScript, NaN ==> NaN => false. But we consider two NaN as equal)
>
> Both values represent the same regular expression (In JavasScript, /abc/ == /abc/ => false.  But we consider two regular expressions as equal when their textual representation matches).

So, if you're getting a false for `.equals()`, then we can conclude the following:

1. The two are not the same object so they don't pass `===`
2. Both values are not NaN (you are presumably working with objects anyway)
3. Both values are not the same regex

So, that only leaves the 2nd item in the documentation which means that either the objects are not the same type or some of their properties are not the same.  For anyone to help you further on what exactly is different between them, we'd have to see the actual objects or the code that creates them.

If you have the non-minimized version of angular installed in your page, you could also just step through your call to `angular.equals()` and see which step in the code it is finding the difference.

Or, if there are a lot of properties or a lot of objects so stepping in the debugger is difficult, you could write your own little debug routine to tell you which property was different.  That would look something like this:

```
function compareObjects(s, t) {
    if (typeof s !== typeof t) {
        console.log("two objects not the same type");
        return;
    }
    if (typeof s !== "object") {
        console.log('arguments are not typeof === "object"');
        return;
    }
    for (var prop in s) {
        if (s.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (t.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (!angular.equals(s[prop], t[prop])) {
                    console.log("property " + prop + " does not match");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("second object does not have property " + prop);
            }
        }
    }
    // now verify that t doesn't have any properties 
    // that are missing from s
    for (prop in t) {
        if (t.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (!s.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                console.log("first object does not have property " + prop);
            }
        }
    }
}


// then call this function on your two objects
// and then look in the debug console to see what it reports
compareObjects(rowData, $scope.grid.backup[i]);
```

Comment: Added more extensive comparison function.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try debugging.

Open developer bar in Chrome, place a `break-point` at the equals function in angular code. Now when the comparison happens Go line by line by stepping over line by line. Check at which point its returning false and you will probably get the reason why.

Or get the equals function from angular source:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/124e9b803ffabee407531da5dd1d3ac6ca1d1ffb/src/Angular.js#L604

Modify it with console logs at each `return false`, and use this function to compare your objects to debug.

Comment: Well, the question does specifically state 'The two objects look equal when I debug'.

Comment: In my opinion if he had traced the code, he would ask pinpointing the condition that broke in `equals`, and probably there wont be this question unless angular has some bug or edge case. Strictly my inference.

Answer (score 0):

[jfriend00's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266509/1028230) is a good start, but isn't very descriptive when the issue is a ways down the object model, as instead of acting recursively, it punts when both objects have the same properties pointing to objects. Instead of walking the object model, it falls back using `angular.equals`.

That is, *jfriend's solution only defers `angular.equals` limitations one level of the object hierarchy.*

For instance, it fails mightily on this test:

```
var obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: {
            e: 3,
            f: 4,
        },
        g: 5,
    },
    h: 6,
};

var obj2 = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: {
            e2: 3, // DIFFERENT PROPERTY
            f: 'different', // DIFFERENT TYPE AND VALUE
        },
        g: 'again', // DIFFERENT TYPE AND VALUE
    },
    h: 7, // DIFFERENT VALUE
};
```

It tells us only:

- property b does not match
- property h does not match

That's not wrong, but it's also not particularly descriptive, and didn't help me find differences between two complex objects when `angular.equals` came up false.

---

#### A better solution

We can improve on that.

If we wanted to know specifically that `[obj].b.d.f` are different values, we'd need to recurse down the object model. We'd also need to recurse down both object models to see when `obj2` has something `obj1` did not. (To do that efficiently, a different function is used for the second comparison.)

Here's a cut that does that, I believe:

```
// The unicorn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234317/1028230
// prettier-ignore
String.prototype.formatUnicorn = String.prototype.formatUnicorn || function () {
    var str = this.toString(); if (arguments.length) { var t = typeof arguments[0]; var key; var args = 'string' === t || 'number' === t ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0]; for (key in args) { str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + key + '\\}', 'gi'), args[key]); } }
    return str;
};

function compareObjects(s, t, propsToIgnore1) {
    return compareFirstToSecond(s, t, propsToIgnore1, '/').concat(
        compareSecondToFirst(t, s, propsToIgnore1, '/')
    );

    function compareFirstToSecond(first, second, propsToIgnore, path) {
        var msgs = [];
        propsToIgnore = propsToIgnore || [];

        // Check type
        if (typeof first !== typeof second) {
            msgs.push(
                path +
                    ' -- two objects not the same type $${0}$${1}$$'.formatUnicorn(
                        typeof first,
                        typeof second
                    )
            );
            return msgs;
        }

        // Check value
        // Keep in mind that typeof null is 'object'
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808270/1028230
        if (typeof first !== 'object' || first === null) {
            if (first !== second) {
                msgs.push(
                    '{2} -- Unequal (null and not null) or (two unequal non-objects): {0}-{1} '.formatUnicorn(
                        first,
                        second,
                        path
                    )
                );
            }
            return msgs;
        }

        // Check properties
        for (var prop in first) {
            if (propsToIgnore.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
                if (first.hasOwnProperty(prop) && first[prop] !== undefined) {
                    if (second.hasOwnProperty(prop) && second[prop] !== undefined) {
                        msgs = msgs.concat(
                            compareFirstToSecond(
                                first[prop],
                                second[prop],
                                propsToIgnore,
                                path + prop + '/'
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        msgs.push(path + prop + ' -- second object does not have property ' + prop);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return msgs;
    }

    // now verify that t doesn't have any properties
    // that are missing from s.
    // To recurse this properly, let's set up another function.
    function compareSecondToFirst(second, first, propsToIgnore, path) {
        var msgs = [];
        propsToIgnore = propsToIgnore || [];

        for (var prop in second) {
            if (propsToIgnore.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
                if (second.hasOwnProperty(prop) && second[prop] !== undefined) {
                    if (!first.hasOwnProperty(prop) || first[prop] === undefined) {
                        msgs.push(path + prop + ' -- first object does not have property ' + prop);
                    } else if (
                        typeof first[prop] === 'object' &&
                        typeof second[prop] === 'object'
                    ) {
                        // NOTE: To make this proceed down the object tree, even though we've already
                        // checked equality for each match, we need to keep recursively calling
                        // a check to see if the second object's object model has a prop the first's
                        // model does not.
                        //
                        // That is, we don't know what "props of props" are missing all the way
                        // down the object model without this call. But we're recursively calling this
                        // inner function so we don't do any extra comparision work.
                        msgs = msgs.concat(
                            compareSecondToFirst(
                                second[prop],
                                first[prop],
                                propsToIgnore,
                                path + prop + '/'
                            )
                        );
                    } // else they aren't objects and we already know the props values match, as they've already been checked.
                }
            }
        }

        return msgs;
    }
}
```

This will tell us not just what's different but the path down the object model to where each difference lives. It also has something that's important to me: The ability to skip properties with the `propsToIgnore` array parameter. Your use case may differ, of course.

- /b/d/e -- second object does not have property e
- /b/d/f/ -- two objects not the same type $$number$$string$$
- /b/g/ -- two objects not the same type $$number$$string$$
- /h/ -- Unequal (null and not null) or (two unequal non-objects): 6-7
- /b/d/e2 -- first object does not have property e2

That's getting closer to helping us know what's different, I believe. As you can imagine, as the objects become more complex, having this drill down reporting becomes more useful.

Here's the requisite fiddle of reasonable success with the two `compareObjects` methods and results:

https://jsfiddle.net/t4oh7qu9/1/