# Why typeof (null) == 'object' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just noticed that following expression is `true` in JavaScript:

```
typeof (null) == 'object'
```

That seems really weird, suppose I have a variable with `null` value and `typeof` returns `object` for this variable!

I want to know why `typeof (null)` is `object` in JavaScript?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object?rq=1

Comment: Because the spec says so: https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been debated (see for example [this discussion](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=discussion%3atypeof)), and it's often seen as not really good, but it has a rationale : A `null` value takes the place of an object, it's the value you have when you expect an object and have none.

From [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.11) :

> null : primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value.

It's exactly the same as `NaN` being of type `"number"`.

Comment: Also, changing it now might break stuff.

Comment: Of course. Personally I find it so logical and coherent that I almost like it like it is. Except I **never** found a case where it was useful to have `typeof null` being `"object"`...

Comment: But it's not the same as `NaN`. The IEEE 754 floating point standard describes a value `NaN` to represent an invalid result. So it really is of data type `number`, but its name just doesn't fit very well. But back to the topic, I really why there was proper operator built in that returns the true data type of a value. `typeof` is just messed up. Not sure right now what ES6 adds in this regard.

Comment: The fact I see it as logically coherent and you don't, and that there's no definite argument, lets me think we should have closed the question as off-topic rather than as duplicate.

Comment: Depends on the "why" of the question. Is it "why does the operator behave like this" or "why was it decided that the operator behaves like this"? The former is answerable by pointing to the space. The latter would rather require an email to Brendan Eich. Anyways, there is no value in discussing this any further.

Comment: Given the number of times this was discussed, Brendan would probably rather not receive another mail on this topic :)

Comment: Ehehe true :) It seems there is no search for http://esdiscuss.org/, that could probably give us an answer.

Answer (score -1):

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0. null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms). Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return value

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Did you just copy [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808270/218196)? **edit:** Oh no you didn't, you just quote the same resource.... weird though. That's why it's good to mark quotes as such, like `> Quoted text goes here`.

Comment: Both answers are copying part of the MDN article verbatim anyway...

Comment: I just wanted to note that this answer doesn't actually deserve to be downvoted. As established, it just quotes MDN, although this could have been made clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry and thanks for the edit. The next times i'll use quote.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't hurt to be explicit about it, like *"MDN says: > text*"