# Typeof operator resturns a string than null

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to Js.
Now I have this code

```
var name = null;
console.log(typeof name);
```

But the result is a string? why is that? why not null?

Comment: typeof null should be "object" due to a wonderful js bug that will never be fixed.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is returning "string" in certain cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is typeof null "object"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the data type of `null` is actually an object, rather than actually being `null`.

Because of this, when you call typeof, it will return a string of "undefined" (or "null"), rather than the `null` value you're expecting.

You can read more about how JavaScript handles it on the [official specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3).

JavaScript values were initially represented as a tag and a value, with the tag for objects being 0, and null was represented as the standard null pointer. 
This led to problems with typeof returning a tag of 0 for nulls.

Because of this, this statement will always pass as true:

```
 typeof null === 'object';
```

There was a proposed fix for this, but it was rejected as it would have caused problems with existing code that used this "trick" to validate nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Although it returns "null", that is purely typeof's way of informing you what it's type is... it's not actually returning us a type of the type your testing, does that make sense?

Test any type and it will return it as a "string", "object" etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with a global variable wherever you are running your code.  Due to a longstanding bug that will never be fixed, the typeof a null reference is evaluated to object.

```
var a = null;
typeof a
// => "object"
```

However, in certain environments it appears that the specific variable name is set to the values such as "null" or "", meaning it would evaluate to string

```
name
//=> "null"
typeof name
//=> "string"
```

To try this out, go ahead an open a javascript console on stackoverflow and type

```
name
//=> ""
```