# using null as an expected object

Tags: javascript, object, null, prototype-programming

> The value `null` represents the *intentional absence* of any object value.
>
> In APIs, `null` is often retrieved in place where an *object can be expected* but no object is relevant.
>
> — [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) (emphasis mine)

**TL;DR: [Why does `null.content` throw an error but `false.content` returns `undefined`](https://twitter.com/harveybars/status/746341973188022273)?**

In my project’s API, I have methods allowing the user to set and get an icon of a Page.

```
Page.prototype.setIcon = function (key) {
  this.icon = database.find(function (item) { return item.content === key })
}
Page.prototype.getIconContent = function () {
  return this.icon.content
}
```

A string is given as the argument, and the program searches the database for an object whose `content` property equals the given argument. If no such object is found, [the `find()` function will return `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). So `this.icon` will be set to `undefined`.

This is not good because when the user calls `getIconContent()`, they will *receive an error*, because the program is trying to find the `content` property of `undefined`.

What I want to happen is that if no such object in the database is found, `setIcon()` will set `this.icon` to a falsy value that *will not throw an error* when attempting to get the `content` property. So I tried using OR `null`, as [it is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object).

```
Page.prototype.setIcon = function (key) {
  this.icon = database.find(function (item) { return item.content === key }) || null
}
```

But this didn’t work because trying to get `null.content` *will still throw an error*. So then I tried OR `false` and it works the way I want.

```
Page.prototype.setIcon = function (key) {
  this.icon = database.find(function (item) { return item.content === key }) || false
}
```

So when a user calls `setIcon()` with no argument, and then tries `getIconContent()`, they will not receive an error, because `false.content` doesn’t throw an error; it returns `undefined`, which is the behavior I’m looking for.

My question is, why is `false` the correct usage, when clearly the expected type of `icon` should be an object? I would think `null` would be more “semantically correct,” but it throws an error.

---

PS: In addition to `false`, these are other falsy values that don’t throw errors:

```
var a = 0;   a.content // returns `undefined`
var b = NaN; b.content // returns `undefined`
var c = '';  c.content // returns `undefined`
```

The empty object `{}`, even though it is truthy

```
var d = {}; d.content // returns `undefined`
```

`undefined` throws an error as expected

```
var e; e.content // throws an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"
```

Comment: Duck typing is weird, and null in javascript is even weirder. I would just create a dummy object with all the needed properties, and return that instead of null.

Comment: Note that the link you point to as evidence of `null` being an object explicitly says it is not an object. `typeof null === 'object'`, but `null` is not an object. The answers note that this is due to the spec saying that's what `typeof` should return, irrespective of its actual implementation. `null` is actually a primitive value, just like `object`.

Comment: Concur with @Mike McCaughan.  This question is probably a duplicate of the page you linked: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object].

Comment: I see. But even though `typeof null` should be `'null'` (and not `'object'` as that’s a bug), I stand by my original question of why `false` stands a better chance than `null` of testing for properties, when `null` is explicitly said to be used *where an object is expected*. @JuanTomas I agree that question is related, but I don't think this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Well, checking for `null` when you expect an object reference is kind of standard for most programming languages. Search SO for NullReferenceException and start wading...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah, good thinking. So you're saying maybe my flaw is rather in `Page.prototype.getIcon`?

Comment: It's arguably a defect in the language.  For some obscure historical reason, `typeof null` equals `object`, even though `null` is really nothing, no object.  So why does `false` fare better in this context?  Because `false` is a thing, a boolean.  Using `false` in this way seems kind of a code smell to me.  Probably the most readable solution is a ternary operator in `..getIcon()` to explicitly check for `null`, as you and @Mike McCaughan suggest.

Comment: Agreed. If one of you could post an answer, that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: In your `getIcon` you should check if `this.icon` exists and the return its content. But I would expect that is should be either called `getIconContent`, return `this.icon` or that your `this.icon` should be actually the value of `this.icon.content`.

Comment: @t.niese `this.icon` needs to be an actual object because of other methods not shown in this question.

Comment: That might be true but then I would name `this.icon` differently. Because it is not logical why `this.getIcon` returns something different then the `this.icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` is a boolean. Booleans are boxable (like numbers and strings) because there is a `Boolean` constructor in the language. When you try to access `false.content`, it becomes an object, nearly (but not quite, because it's still of type `"boolean"`) what you'd get from `new Boolean(false)`. Being an object, it can have properties. It's just that booleans have no useful properties (unlike strings which have `length` etc) so you never see them used that way.

On the other hand, there is no `Null` constructor that could box the value `null` of type `"null"` (or indeed type `"object"` in older versions of ECMAScript). So there is no valid way to interpret `null.content`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the reasoning behind the meat of the question!

Answer (score 2):

The trick with `null` is that, while `typeof null === 'object'`, `null` itself is actually its own type of primitive. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object) for a more in-depth discussion, including excerpts from the relevant specification.

`null` is a valid thing to return for when an object is expected, but it is incumbent upon consumers to check the return value for the `null` value. For instances where it goes wrong, simply see the tag [nullreferenceexception](/questions/tagged/nullreferenceexception) and the numerous questions about handling that scenario.

Whether or not you should be returning `null`, `undefined`, or some other value from your `getIcon` method is really a design question, prone to opinions rather than facts, so I'll refrain from offering mine.