# js determine type of a variable

Tags: javascript

Given:

```js
let item = {
  id: xxx,
  name: yyy
};
console.log(typeof item.id, item.id, Object.keys(item.id).length)
```

I get:

```
object, null, TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I'm confused. How can I determinte the correct type?

thanks

Comment: You have an extra `.id` in your arguments call. It should be `Object.keys(item).length`

Comment: `typeof null` is object. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808252/2964675)

Comment: it does work as long as the `xxx` and `yyy` are valid things, try replacing them with something like a string.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You're logging 3 different things, which one is giving you the result you don't understand? Your test case uses the variables `xxx` and `yyy`, which you never define, so it stops on line one with a reference error.

Comment: MarcoL, thanks. Please answer, so I can accept it.