# Why can't I compare `typeof x` to "null" or "MyClass" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote some code to do some runtime type tests:

```
var x = window.opener;
if (typeof x === 'null') {
  // Do something
}
var y = getSomething();
if (typeof y === 'MyClass') {
  // ...
} else if (typeof y === 'array') {
  // ...
}
```

I got this error on all the `if` expressions:

> error TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"null"'.

Is this a TypeScript bug? Why doesn't it allow me to use `typeof` like I want to?

Comment: (note: behavior is specific to TypeScript 2.2 so this does not occur in the TypeScript Playground yet)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### This isn't what `typeof` does!

The [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) takes an expression and returns one of the following values*:

- `"string"`
- `"number"`
- `"boolean"`
- `"symbol"`
- `"undefined"`
- `"object"`
- `"function"`

You will *not* see `typeof` produce values like `"null"`, `"Array"`, or the name of a user-defined class. Note that `typeof null` is `"object"` for [sad reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object).

#### Oops! What do I do instead?

So you thought `typeof` was cooler than it was. Oh well!

- To test for `null`, use `expr === null`. You can use the idiomatic `expr == null` to test for `undefined` and `null` if your coworkers let you get away with using `==`
- To test for an array, use `Array.isArray(expr)`. Note that some things you expect to be arrays, like `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`, aren't (`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`), so be careful
- To test for a class type use `expr instanceof ClassName`

#### I got 99 problems and IE8 is one of them

If you are really sure that you have an object and runtime combination that produces a different value (as in, you actually tested it, and it really did produce some other string), use a type assertion on either side of the test:

```
if (typeof x === <string>"magicthinger") {
```

---

`*` In *ancient* browsers (IE8) when querying `typeof` of some exotic browser objects, you might get other values, but no modern JavaScript engine does this.