# How to check if it is a JsonArray or JsonObject in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So my json data is something like the following,

```
{
  "amazon": []
},
{
  "flipkart": {
    "product_store": "Flipkart",
    "product_store_logo": "logo url",
    "product_store_url": "shop url",
    "product_price": "14999",
    "product_offer": "",
    "product_color": "",
    "product_delivery": "3-4",
    "product_delivery_cost": "0",
    "is_emi": "1",
    "is_cod": "1",
    "return_time": "10 Days"
  }
},
{
  "snapdeal": []
}
```

So here I want to loop through each shop and check if it is a jsonarray(amazon) or jsonobject(flipkart) then delete those empty array. And add it to a new array.

Just like the example all keys who have no values like amazon and snapdeal are arrays. And keys with values are jsonObject. I can't change the json.

So I want to know how can I detect JSONObject and JSONArray...

Thank you..

Comment: *"How to check if it is a JsonArray or JsonObject in Javascript"* -- there is no such thing like *JsonArray* or *JsonObject*. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is just text. It is the text representation of some data structure. Incidentally, it uses JavaScript notation for that. If you don't have it in a string then it is JavaScript and nothing else. If you have it in a string then you decode it to JavaScript data structures (arrays or objects) but they are not JSON and/or related to JSON in any way.

Comment: Well in modern JavaScript you've got [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: Did you read the description of the tag `json` when you added it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if it is array:

```
if (Array.isArray(json['amazon'])) {
  // It is array
}
```

and you can check if type of object is `object` to determine if it is an object. Please refer, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808252/2633956) for the reason why check for null is separate:

```
if (json['flipkart'] !== null && typeof (json['flipkart']) === 'object') {
  // It is object
}
```

Comment: `typeof (json['amazon'])` gives `object` too :)

Comment: Of course because `Array` is `Object` in JavaScript, that's why here is dedicated method to check specifically for `Array` was added

Answer (score 3):

### Array

If you are working with Jquery you can use **isArray()** Jquery function, doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/).

```
if($.isArray(your_array)){
   //You code
}
```

Without Jquery, only Javascript use **Array.isArray**, more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp).

```
if(Array.isArray(your_array)){
   //You code
}
```

### Object

If you are working with Jquery you can use **type()** Jquery function, and compare with 'object' type, doc [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/).

```
if(jQuery.type(your_objet) === 'object'){
   //You code
}
```

Without Jquery, only Javascript use **typeof**, more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp).

```
if(typeof (your_object) === 'object'){
   //You code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript arrays are objects too, so if you use `typeof` you will get the same result `object` in both cases, In your case I would use  `instanceof` operator Or `Array.isArray` Like Flying's answer.

```
[] instanceof Array => true
{} instanceof Array => false

Array.isArray( [] ) => true
Array.isArray( {} ) => false
```

Here is a working example using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to retrieve only object instance from your json:

```js
  var json = [
    {
      "amazon": []
    },
    {
      "flipkart": {
        "product_store": "Flipkart",
        "product_store_logo": "logo url",
        "product_store_url": "shop url",
        "product_price": "14999",
        "product_offer": "",
        "product_color": "",
        "product_delivery": "3-4",
        "product_delivery_cost": "0",
        "is_emi": "1",
        "is_cod": "1",
        "return_time": "10 Days"
      }
    },
    {
      "snapdeal": []
    }
  ];
  
var result = json.filter( function (item) {
  // get the first property 
  var prop = item[ Object.keys(item)[0] ];
  return !(prop instanceof Array);
  // OR
  // return !Array.isArray(prop);
});

console.log(result);
```