# Why null does not have a __proto__?

Tags: javascript

null in JS is considered as an object. typeof null == "object" //true

Then why does null not have a `__proto__`. All objects should have a `__proto__` in JS

```js
var n = null;
console.log(n.__proto__);   //Cannot read property '__proto__' of null`
```

Can someone provide a detailed answer?

Comment: `null` isn't actually an object, it's a primitive. http://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `null` in JS is considered as an object. typeof null == "object" //true

As already mentioned, `null` is actually a **primitive value** (like `undefined`, a Boolean value, a String value, a Number value, or a symbol) . But the language spec dictates that `typeof null` returns the string `"object"`. (Similarly the specification dictates to return `"function"` for *function objects* instead of `"object"`, like it does for *array objects*)

But that's only one half of the story.

> Then why does null not have a `__proto__`

You might be wondering:

> > Why can I access the protoype of a string value (`"foo".__proto__`) but not `null` if both are primitive values ?

That's because Booleans, Strings and Numbers have object equivalents (`e.g. new String("foo")`) and when you try to access a property on a boolean/number/string primitive, they are internally converted to an object value

```js
console.log("foo".slice)
// does `new String("foo").slice` internally
```

However for `undefined` and `null`, no such object equivalents exist, hence the error.

```js
try {
  console.log(null.foo);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

try {
  console.log(undefined.foo);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

> All objects should have a `__proto__` in JS

Not necessarily. It is possible to create objects without a prototype via `Object.create`:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj.__proto__);
```

Answer (score 3):

`typeof null == "object"` is a mistake, it's not actually an object. See [why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object) for more details about why `typeof` considers it to be an object.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN web docs:

> A primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not
>   an object and has no methods. In JavaScript, there are 6 primitive
>   data types: string, number, boolean, **null**, undefined, symbol (new in
>   ECMAScript 2015).
>
> Most of the time, a primitive value is represented directly at the
>   lowest level of the language implementation.
>
> All primitives are immutable, i.e., they cannot be altered. It is
>   important not to confuse a primitive itself with a variable assigned a
>   primitive value. The variable may be reassigned a new value, but the
>   existing value can not be changed in the ways that objects, arrays,
>   and functions can be altered.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Furthermore:

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were
>   represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0.
>   null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms).
>   Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return
>   value.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null