# About JS datatype Null

Tags: javascript, null

JS datatype Null is used when the programmer explicitly indicates that the value is empty. So when we use the operator typeof on null type variables, we can get the object instead of null as a result. If so, is null an abstract concept  defined by need? Is there any way to print the null type by operator typeof?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Comment: @user202729 Thank you. You made me clear. I edited my question.