# How to check if an object contains a null value?

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
let myObject = {first: "", second: null};
```

And I have a function:

```
return Object.values(myObject).some(
   objectValue => objectValue !== "" && typeof objectValue !== "undefined" && typeof objectValue !== null
);
```

What this does is that it returns `true` if an object has a set value and returns `false` if an object doesn't have any set values. The thing is that when I pass a `null` value, this function returns `true` (as if the object has a set value).

On other occasions it works fine. What is wrong here?

Comment: Your check is incorrect: typeof null is "object", not "null". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object. Compare with `null` literal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` and `undefined` are falsy so you can only write this

```
return Object.values(myObject).some(
  objectValue => objectValue?true:false;
 );
```

null will return false in this case.

Comment: You can simplify this and eliminate the ternary expression:  `!!objectValue`

Comment: it would be better to compare this way: `objectValue === null`, because `objectValue` will be as `false` for every falsy value like `0`, `NaN` etc.