# How does JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) deep clone an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm searching articles about deep clone javascript obj on the web, but most of them said that using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` can do it, however,
do not explain why this method will deep clone obj?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` transforms the entire object into JSON. `JSON.parse` takes JSON and constructs a new object.

Comment: …and JSON is just a string. There's no way a string can hold any sort of reference to an object…

Comment: In addition to what @VLAZ has said, it doesn't actually clone everything. It won't copy functions or custom type information like JS classes. You're limited to some primitives like numbers, booleans, strings, object and arrays.

Comment: @Soc also, it would strip away all `undefined`, so if a property has `undefined` as the value, it will be similarly gone, as if it was a function.

Comment: But `null`s are good... because `null` is an object.

Comment: @VLAZ
Thank you for your answer. I got some understand.

Comment: @Soc no, actually [the `typeof` output is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object) in the first version of JS but was kept for backwards compatibility. The reason `null` works is because [the JSON standard defines it as a valid value](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 2):

JSON.stringify turns a JavaScript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string, eg:

```
var my_object = { key_1: "some text", key_2: true, key_3: 5, key_6: [{}] };

var object_as_string = JSON.stringify(my_object);  
// "{"key_1":"some text","key_2":true,"key_3":5,"key_6":[{}]}"

typeof(object_as_string);  
// "string"
```

So here, all the `objects` and `array` has lost it's reference.

And when we do `JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into a JavaScript object, eg:

```
var object_as_string_as_object = JSON.parse(object_as_string);  
// {key_1: "some text", key_2: true, key_3: 5, key_6: Array(1)}

typeof(object_as_string_as_object);  
// "object"
```

Now the resulting objects got the new storage reference. Let's test it by checking the reference of `array` inside the parent `object` an example.

```
my_object.key_6 === my_object.key_6
// true
```

But, if we try

```
 my_object.key_6 === object_as_string_as_object.key_6
// false
```