# Is null a primitive type or object type?

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive
In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods. There are 6 primitive data types: string, number, bigint, boolean, undefined, and symbol. There also is null, which is seemingly primitive, but indeed is a special case for every Object: and any structured type is derived from null by the Prototype Chain.

but in Javascript the definitve guide, it says
Any Javascript value that is not a number, a string, a boolean, a symbol, a null, or undefined is an object.

So which one is right? Is null an object or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm still confused. The link above (which has 1500 upvotes) says null is an object, and the answer below says its a primitive.

Comment: Although `typeof null` will return "object", `null` is a primitive value of the type "null" (and the only value of that type.) Check out this question for some insight into the issue with the `typeof` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object

Answer (score 9):

When in doubt, read [the official specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-overview), which is essentially the Word of God for JavaScript.

> A primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, **Null**, Boolean, Number, BigInt, String, and Symbol; an object is a member of the built-in type Object; and a function is a callable object. A function that is associated with an object via a property is called a method.

So, yes, `null` is a primitive value.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see null, Arrays, and Objects all output type 'object' when passed to `typeof`.

```js
console.log(typeof null); console.log(typeof []); console.log(typeof {});
```

This, however, is not the same as the [Object type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type).

If you wish to test for types like you're thinking and as defined by ECMAScript, you might want to check this out.

```js
function getType(mixed){
  if(mixed === null){
    return 'null';
  }
  else if(mixed instanceof Array){
    return 'array';
  }
  return typeof mixed;
}

class Test{
  constructor(){
  }
  method(){
    return this;
  }
}
function ConstructorTest(){
  let privateVarsOk;
  this.method = ()=>{
    return this;
  }
}
const test = new Test; constructorTest = new ConstructorTest;

console.log(getType(null));
console.log(getType('4'));
console.log(getType(4));
console.log(getType(['a', 2, 'c']));
console.log(getType({}));
console.log(getType(getType));
console.log(getType(function(){}));
console.log(getType(()=>{}));
console.log(getType(Test));
console.log(getType(test));
console.log(getType(ConstructorTest));
console.log(getType(constructorTest));
console.log(getType());
```

Notice that `class`es are actually functions though, as they do no introduce a new hierarchy.

Comment: There's a difference between lowercase `object` from `typeof` and uppercase `Object` which is a builtin `constructor` function.  e.g. `null instanceof Object` is `false` and `[].constructor` is `Array`.

Comment: @BryanGrace, notice that I just test for `mixed === null` since I have that argument there, so it will return what OP wants. I know that `instanceof` is not the same as `typeof` already. By the way, a `constructor` is a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nullVar=null;
console.log("Data type of nullVar is :"+ (typeof nullVar));
```

o/p;-Data type of nullVar is :object

Null is primitive datatype but it returns object ... So, null return bogus return value ..