# Why are "null" and "undefined" objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

Why are typeof `null` and `undefined` objects instead of keywords or booleans in JavaScript?

For example,

```
(typeof null)
// "object"
(typeof undefined)
// "undefined"
```

But the thing is with `undefined` is that it acts like an object without properties.
But `typeof null` is an object.
Why are they objects and what is the point of them being objects without properties?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object

Comment: Because [that's how the language was designed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#null_type) - in twelve days.

Comment: Neither `null` nor `undefined` is an object. `null` _is_ a keyword and a value of the Null type. `undefined` is not a keyword, but it is a global immutable property of `globalThis` and a value of the Undefined type. `typeof` is broken. The types are listed in the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/#sec-ecmascript-language-types). `typeof null` is also not an object; it’s a string. How did you arrive at the conclusion that `undefined` acts like an object without properties?

Comment: Booleans are `true` and `false`; they are unrelated to `null` and `undefined`. (Oh, I see, it’s you, the author of that `Array.prototype.some` answer from yesterday.)

Comment: Yes that's me, I actually ask understandable questions.