# Why typeof number|null is 'object'?

Tags: typescript

Reproducible code:

```
class MyObject{
    id: number|null = null
}

const a = new MyObject()
console.log(typeof a.id)
```

> 'object'

Is there a way to get the `'number'` type from that property?

Edit:

I understand why `typeof null` is `object`. But my question is: is there a way (maybe reflection or something) to get that `number|null` complete type.

Comment: `typeof null` is `"object"` for historical reasons. [Why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18808226)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Comment: More importantly, this might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [The type information is only available at compiletime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). At runtime there is no knowledge of what a variable or property *might* be. Just what the current value it is. For example `foo: string|number = 1` will never reveal it might have a string at runtime.

Comment: `typeof` does not return the ‘compile’ time type, only the runtime type.

Comment: and is there another approach to get the compile time type?. I mean in other languages when I declare an optional type for a property Optional<Int> I can get the full Optional<Int> type.

Comment: There is no way to get the `number` type from `id` at runtime, unless you make sure to always assign a number to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the type `number` of your new object, you need to assign a value to it.