# my javascript function executes a block of code in if statement even when the condition is not true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a function that fetchs a json data from a server and it must fetch the data if only the condition is met, but it excutes the block even if the condition is `false`

```
const getOfferingCourses = async () => {
    if (typeof loggerInfo === "object") {
      if (typeof loggerInfo.section) {
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("getOfferingCourse", loggerInfo.section);
        let dep = await fetch(baseUrl + "enroll.php", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
          body: formdata,
        });
        let depa = await dep.json();
        if (typeof depa !== "undefined") {
          if (depa.status === "success") {
            setOffeing(depa.data.offering);
            setOffCourses(depa.data.courses);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

this is the error I got:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'section')
    at getSchedule (s-schedule.js:43:1)
    at s-schedule.js:61:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
```

Comment: condition might be wrong, I don't think `null` is the same type as `undefined`

Comment: Which specific line of code produces the error?  When you debug and pause on that line of code, what are the observed values being used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Answer (score 1):

the error occures when you try to check `if (typeof loggerInfo.section)` but as mentioned `loggerInfo` is `null`. 
 you may wonder how this is possible inside `if (typeof loggerInfo === "object")` but `typeof null` is equal to `"object"` so you need to add another condition in the first `if` statement:

```
if(typeof loggerInfo === "object" && loggerInfo !== null)
```

also update the second `if` statement this way:

```js
if (typeof loggerInfo.section !== "undefined")
```

or

```js
if (loggerInfo.section)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys i gave the if condition the loggerinfo it self so it will be falsy in both null or undefined so it won't pass in both cases

```
if(loggerinfo){
// bluh bluh bluh
}
```

and it's working

Answer (score 0):

References

[Differences between null and undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null)

[why is type of null and object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Checkout this example
we have null and undefined variables here, we check the type of each of them and while undefined is indeed undefined, null is considered an object.

This line `if (typeof loggerInfo === "object") {` if `loggerInfo` is null then the condition will be true and it will try to read the next line `if (typeof loggerInfo.section) {` which causes the error

```js
let depa = null;
let depa2 = undefined;

let nullVar = typeof depa;
let unVar = typeof depa2;

console.log(nullVar)
console.log(unVar)
```